# how to display git log data in bootstrao-vue table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component

I have a backed function that gets git logs, filters them and send them to the front end API. The front end gets the data as it's suppose to, I'm trying to bind it to the one of the `data` properties in `Vue.JS`. The data retrieved can be seen bellow:

```
[ { author: 'Yury Stanev',
    email: 'yury.stanev@menlolab.com',
    message: 'test',
    hash: '9807965a9b00f44fd7eb9611cead6445bb472eb9',
    date: '2019-08-28 12:13:28 -0400' },
  { author: 'Yury Stanev',
    email: 'yury.stanev@menlolab.com',
    message: 'added a file',
    hash: '704c86ef685d31a0de1589e5d3db16dd483bebc3',
    date: '2019-08-28 12:08:45 -0400' } ]
```

My Vue component attemps to bind this to the `data().gitCommits` defined earlier.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- <b-table
      striped
      hover
      :git-commits="gitCommits"
    />-->

    <!-- TODO: fix table issue -->
    <ul id>
      <li v-for="log in gitCommits">
        Author: {{ log.author }}
        <br>
        E-Mail: {{ log.email }}
        <br>
        Commit Message: {{ log.message }}
        <br>
        Hash: {{ log.hash }}
        <br>
        Date: {{ log.date }}
        <br>
        <br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'GitLog',
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      err: false,
      gitCommits: [],
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchCommits();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchCommits() {
      this.$socket.emit('project.gitLog', {
        owner: this.$route.params.owner,
        name: this.$route.params.name,
      }, (data) => {
        if (data.err) {
          console.error(data.err);
          return;
        }

        // console.log('DATA:\n', data);
        this.gitCommits = data.files;
        // console.log('gitCommits -> ', typeof (this.gitCommits), this.gitCommits);
        // console.log('Array -> ', Array.isArray(this.gitCommits));
        // console.log('gitCommins:\n', this.gitCommits);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm able to see the data, it's an array of objects. I'm able to show it on the page using `<ul><li v-for="log in gitCommits">  </li></ul>`, but can't get it show up using `<b-table>` something seems to go wrong with how I tie the array to the table.

The middle where to send git log data from the backed is bellow:

```
const debug = require('debug')('SOCKET:project.gitLog');

const menlolabGitManage = require('@menlolab/git-manage-client');

// Middlewares
const hasProject = require('../../middlewares/has-project.socket'); // data.project = {info, package}

module.exports = ctx => async (data, ack) => {
  debug(ctx.userId, data);
  await ctx.sessionCheck();
  await hasProject(ctx, data);

  const gitLog = await menlolabGitManage.gitLog({
    owner: data.project.owner,
    repo: data.project.name,
  });

  console.log(gitLog);

  ack({ files: gitLog });
};
```

Comment: don;t try to convert implicitly gitCommits in console.log to string. Simply call console.log('gitCommits', this.gitCommits);

Comment: OK, that's fine, I've fixed it. But my main issue is to get to display in the table.

Comment: I tried to help you to see what is in the gitCommits. Is it an array or an object?

Comment: Doing typeof(this.gitCommits) says its an object.

Comment: typeof([]) also says "object" because JS array is object too. Look at console output console.log('gitCommits', this.gitCommits) and you will see either it is array or object.

Comment: it's an array of objects.

Comment: The image with the data can be seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/VYHrvys).

Comment: Try this.gitCommits = data.files;

Comment: That's what I had initially, tries it again just now, nothing chnaged.

Comment: Hmm. It seems I didnot look at this issue correctly. Did you try <b-table
      striped
      hover
      :items="gitCommits" /> ?

Comment: Well, that fixed it, but I'm not to sure why. Is `:items="..."` reserved for the table?

Comment: Yes, see documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/

Comment: The table declares exact prop for items. You cannot assign any name  to this prop for a component you want. This is by design.

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for the help.